# Efficiently look up large Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries, 140000 records and 485000 records.

```
dict1 = {'key1' : [['value1',count1],[value3,count3]...], 
    'key2' : [['value2',count2],[value4,count4].....], 
    ...}

dict2 = {'value1' : [(countA,info1,ind1),(countB,info2,ind2)....], 
    'value2': [(countC,info3,ind3),(countD,info4,ind4)....],
    ...}
```

For each key in dict1, I need the corresponding information related to value field from dict2.  I have used for loops and the code works fine but it takes a lot of time.

Please let me know if this can be optimised.

Comment: Show what you have done and provide a reproducible example that is sample input and output

Comment: And show an example of what result you want.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would update your title as this is not what I would commonly define as merging dictionaries and I almost voted to close it as a duplicate until I realised you actually want to do a lookup

Comment: Have you tried `dict(dict1).update(dict2)`?

Comment: No I have not tried dict(dict1).update(dict2). I do not quite understand the syntax though. I will check it out.

Comment: So for `key1`, what output do you need?  Everything in dict2 for `value1` and all other items in `dict1['key1']`?  Do you have to multiply by the `count1`, `count3`, etc. values?  Are the value arrays in dict1 relatively short, or very long?  How about in dict2?  There may be lots of opportunities to optimize, but it depends on these other dimensions to your problem.

Comment: I have managed to optimise it to some extent. Instead of using 'if value1 in dict2.keys(): ' , I used try: dict2[value1] ... except continue construct. This works fine form me now. Thanks everyone for the suggestions and sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Python dictionary lookup is O(1), so the speed should not be affected by the size (at least once your grown beyond the limits of what fits in to cache).